# Adding multiple selected values from an array to a Kendo Multi Select

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-multiselect

**Background:**

I getting values from a db that will be needed to be pre-selected in a kendo multi select.  I am able to do this with one word, however when the return value from the DB is multiple words I run into problems.

**Problem:**

I am not able to populate pre-selected values in my kendo multi select.  In the best cases when I only get one returned word I am able to run these two lines `var value = multiSelect.value(); multiSelect.value(["test"]);` and the multi select would be populated with the test selection.  However when I do multiple values from an array, it does not work the same way.

**Code:**

```
var keyWordPool = [{Words: "Test"},{Words: "Test2"}, {Words: "Test3"}, 
                   {Words: "Test4"},{Words: "Test5"}];

var returnedWords = ["Test","Test4", "Test5"]; **<< This does not work**
var returnedWords = ["Test"]; **<< This does work** 

CreateandPopulateMultiSelect(keyWordPool, returnedWords)

function CreateandPopulateMultiSelect(dataSource, wordsToPopulate)
{
   var multiSelect = $(".PanelMultiSelect").kendoMultiSelect({
        dataSource: dataSource,
        filter: "contains",
        dataTextField: "Words",
        dataValueField: "Words",
        select: function (e) {
            var item = e.item;
            var text = item.text();
            var stop = 0;
        }
    }).data("kendoMultiSelect");

   var value = multiSelect.value();

   multiSelect.value([wordsToPopulate]);
}
```

**Objective:**

I am not able to control the amount of words that come back from the DB, so I will need to be able to add multiple words at any given time, as well as one word.  I will need to have *wordsToPopulate* to already be selected when a person opens a panel bar.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, I can't tell you exactly what is happening internally in kendo, but your wordsToPopulate variable is already an array when you pass it in to CreateandPopulateMultiSelect().  If you change

```
multiSelect.value([wordsToPopulate]);
```

to

```
multiSelect.value(wordsToPopulate);
```

it should work.

http://dojo.telerik.com/@Stephen/aMEma

Comment: Yup, found that out not so long ago